# Android 4.0 browser overflow: scroll and touch/click events

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, html, css

I've run into a really annoying problem with the stock Android 4.0 browser. I have a div with overflow: scroll, and elements within which scroll horizontally if they exceed the length of the div. The scrolling works fine, but for some reason (only in the Android browser), click/touch events attached to the elements within the div do not get triggered at all, unless you hold your finger on the element and let go EXACTLY at the point in which the highlighting disappears. Just wondering if anybody has encountered this problem and/or has any idea of how to fix it. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the bug seems to only occur when the element bound to a click/tap event within the scrolling container is an anchor (even without href attribute). If it's any other type of element, it works fine.